# Accessing information using AJAX in jQuery and passing data to JSON from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

In my index.php file, I have the following code snippets. Can someone provide an explanation how this process occur ? I found this somewhere and it somehow matches what I intend to do on a work.

```
case 'option1':
$final['a']['b'] = queryDatabase($conn, $id, 'customer');
echo json_encode($final);
```

I have a function ***queryDatabase*** that contains an SQL query.

```
function queryDatabase($conn, $id, $searchType) {
$query = "SELECT .....
```

Then it sets the variable $rows as follows:

```
$rows = query($conn, $query);
```

The variable $query contains the SQL query.

Then I have another function as follows:

```
function query($conn, $query) {
$rows = [];

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if($result) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
 }
return $rows;
}
```

Now in my global.js file, I have created and ajax request as follows:

```
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { 
                 action: 'option1',
                 id: id,
                },
                success:
                function(data) {
```

Also, in the `function(data)`, does the `data` contains all the result retrieved from the database? How can I access individual data from the database here?
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the data should include the result, however, you need to echo back the data to be accessible,

Moreover, you need to encode the result in json, so your last line of code should be something like

```
echo json_encode($rows);
```

After that you can edit your javascript in the success part to log the returned result, something like:

```
console.log(data);
```

This will show you exactly how to access your data.

Comment: Yes I encoded it. 

Can you tell me what does this do ?
function query($conn, $query) {
$rows = [];

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if($result) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
 }
return $rows;
}

Comment: I posted the code on the answer: it should be
echo json_encode($rows);

Comment: also, don't forget the log function will log the data on your browser console, if you are using chrome, just right click and select inspect, then navigate to Console, the data will be there

Comment: Simple, use data.entrezgene.main

Comment: Where does data come from bro ?